# Error with a plot using qplot (ggplot2)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I've been trying for a while to get a plot of a couple of variables I have. Several months ago I could plot it easily using this code:

```
qplot(X, Y, data=Datos, geom=c("point", "smooth"), method="lm", formula= y ~ poly(x, 2))
```

However, when running the code today, I get this error, which annoys me because I don't know why it occurs:

```
ERROR: Unknown parameters
```

I have checked the code, but I didn't find any problem on it, so I don't know why it behaves differently.

Comment: pls don't use `qplot()`. it's deprecated and i spent hours removing most of it from `ggplot2`'s docs. it's not that much longer to write it out in full ggplot2 idioms.

Comment: And which is the updated command to plot figures?

Comment: um…`ggplot()` the main plotting mechanism in ggplot2. `?ggplot` in the console

Comment: Is the problem just that your data `Datos` was loaded in R before and isn't now? +1 on not using `qplot()`

Comment: It was loaded, I checked it several times. Otherwise, which would be the equivalent ggplot command to run the same figure as qplot?

Comment: `ggplot(Datos, aes(x = X, y = Y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2))`

Comment: Thanks Felix. One last question. I want to represent the prediction interval instead the confidence interval, should I write method="lm",interval="prediction"?